# Calculating delivery date ranges based on order cut-off times?

Tags: apex, formula

We are trying to code the following delivery schedule http://www.fragilistics.co.uk/delivery-schedule into Salesforce, such that if a customer orders an item on Friday, Oct 24th and they're in Area 11, a custom field called "Estimated Delivery Date" would be populated with "November 3rd or 4th".  Any way to do this with a formula field, workflow rule or Apex code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid Apex code, this could be done with formulas and workflows

Since it's dependent on the day of the week, I would want to set up a number formula field determining what day of the week it is. Call it `Order_Weekday__c`. A value of 0 would be Sunday, 1 would be Monday, etc. We can also find out what the first day of the week is by subtracting this number from the order date.

```
MOD( {!Order_Date__c} - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7)
```

Then set up a workflow rule for each of the Areas. Entry criteria for Area 1:

```
Area__c == '1'
```

Then the Workflow Field Update for your Estimated Delivery Date text field will be (for Area 1)

```
TEXT(
    if (Order_Weekday__c <= 1,
        (Order_Date__c - Order_Weekday__c + 3),
        if(Order_Weekday__c <= 3,
            (Order_Date__c - Order_Weekday__c + 6),
            if (Order_Weekday__c <= 5,
                (Order_Date__c - Order_Weekday__c + 8),
                (Order_Date__c - Order_Weekday__c + 10)
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

This is a lot to maintain through workflows, so I would probably prefer to use an Apex trigger and a custom object to keep track of these delivery schedules. That way if it ever changes, it's just a matter of editing the object data.